# Every infinite subset $E$ of a compact set $K$ contains a limit point in $K$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We have the following result: Every infinite subset $E$ of a compact set $K$ contains a limit point in $K$. I understand the proof given in Rudin.

Now consider the following statement: *All* limit points of a subset $E$ (not necessarily infinite) of a compact set $K$ are contained in $K$. Clearly this has to be false, since it is much stronger than the first proposition, but I don't understand what's wrong with the following reasoning: Since $K$ is compact, it is closed, so it contains all of it's limit points. Since $E$ is contained in $K$, every limit point of $E$ is a limit point of $K$, and is therefore contained in $K$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with your reasoning: the statement is true, and you don’t in fact need $K$ to be compact: it’s true for any closed set. What *isn’t* true for arbitrary closed sets is the really significant part of the original theorem, which is not that $K$ *contains* the limit point in question: it’s that every infinite subset of $K$ actually *has* a limit point.

Consider the closed set $C=[0,1]\cup\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb R$: $C$ is closed, so it contains all limit points of all of its subsets, but $\Bbb Z$ is an infinite subset of $C$ that has no limit point at all.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. I was confusing the fact that any limit points of E is contained in K with the existence of at least one limit point, which is necessarily contained in K.

Comment: @Joshua: You’re welcome.